# Definition for a bar resolution for a module over a dg category

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $ \mathcal{A}$ be a dg category and define a right $ \mathcal{A}$ module to be a dg functor $ M: \mathcal{A}^{op} \rightarrow dif\  k$ where $dif\ k$ is the category of differential $k$ modules and $k$ is a commutative ring. Let $ I_\mathcal{A}$ be the $ \mathcal{A} -\mathcal{A}$ bimodule that such that $ (A,B)\mapsto \mathcal{A}(A,B)$ for $ A,B \in ob(\mathcal{A})$

In Keller's paper " Derived Invariance Of Higher Structures On The Hochschild Complex" he defines a bar resolution of $ I_\mathcal{A}$ to be the sum total complex $BR(\mathcal{A})$ of the double complex with components which vanish for $p < 0$ and equal:

$ \bigoplus_{A_0, \dots ,A_p} \mathcal{A}(A_p, -) \otimes \mathcal{A}(A_{p-1},A_p)\otimes \dots \otimes \mathcal{A}(A_0,A_1) \otimes \mathcal{A}(-,A_0)$

For $p \geq 0$.

My question is: is it possible to define the bar resolution of an arbitrary module over a dg category? I've poked around the internet and I wasn't successful at finding anything. From this definition I can't see what the general thing should be.

Comment: The definition generalizes in the obvious way for any $\mathscr A$-$\mathscr A$-bimodule $X$, just replace $\mathscr A$ by $X$ in the formula.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @Adeel, I'd buy that. Do you know of a reference just to be sure?

Comment: I don't, sorry.